# Have two ddev containers curl to each other

Tags: ddev

I have both `http://foo.ddev.local` and `http://bar.ddev.local` (two different projects)

I can use `curl` to call them on my host. Now I'd like `foo` to contact `bar`, however if I

```
ddev ssh
http://bar.ddev.local
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: http://bar.ddev.local
```

Comment: You'll probably want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710272/communication-between-two-ddev-projects/53436970#53436970 - The reason you can't do that is that the name `bar.ddev.local` can't be resolved inside the container (it's added to the *host* /etc/hosts file. However, you could `curl ddev-bar-web` (the name of the web container for the "bar" project). That would likely do what you want. There are other ways you might pull it off.  Maybe you can say more about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Perfect, that did the trick. Now both sites can talk with each other via RESTful endpoints

Answer (score 1):

An example of `extra_hosts` for anyone else encountering this issue. I needed to use an HTTPS URL in a Drupal module's UI, `entity_share`, to cURL another ddev site (ie. couldn't use `ddev-bar-web`).

On foo I add a `.ddev/docker-compose.hosts.yaml`

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    extra_hosts:
      - bar.ddev.site:172.18.0.6
```